# Workflow on "Activity"?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm trying to have CRM 2011 share activities to a `Team` if the user that created the record is part of another team.

Firstly, is it possible to create either a custom or basic workflow on "Activities" instead of having to create a workflow on each type of activity (Appointement, Phone Call, E-mail, etc.) that does the same thing on each of them ?

Secondly, I see the basic workflows wizard allows you to `Assign` activities to another team, but I don't see the `Share` action anywhere. Is this a job for a custom, .NET assembly, workflow ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the exact entity when you create a workflow, this means you need to create a worklow for each activity entity-type (1 for Appointment, 1 for Phone Call, ...)

There isn't a built-in share functionality inside the standard Workflow designer, you need to use a custom activity (create one using .NET or install one already compiled)

Check these two:

http://crm2011workflowutils.codeplex.com/

http://crm2011sharestep.codeplex.com/

Comment: So, there is really no way to build a workflow on the "ActivityPointer" entity ? EDIT: Apparently, according the the table in here, no :( http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.ca/2011_10_01_archive.html